# VBA revert cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on  a double click to change a cell value to done ( withing the range)
But i want to be able to double click that cell at any time later and revert back to the original formula. Currently this just replaces the cell with a "DONE" . I need it to check the status of column C5 and replace the original formula. I have the formula saved in another column for each cell  ( S5 ).

What i have so far 
I have also realized i do not need it for multiple columns  D:G is not needed just column D

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rInt As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("D5:G400"))
    If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each rCell In rInt
            rCell.Value = "Done"
        Next
    End If
    Set rInt = Nothing
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Each row has is corresponding dates
Column C  has a start date 01/06/2018
Column D  =(WORKDAY(C5,1,$BJ$2:$BJ$58))
Column S  Has the stored formula of D  =(WORKDAY(C5,1,$BJ$2:$BJ$58))

When i double click a cell in column  D i want to swap between  "Done" and  the formula in S 
for around 400 rows.

Sorry for the multi posts , i was trying to edit the comment and not the original post. Thanks for helping.

The code you have written sort of works but the value in column D comes back as =(WORKDAY(xer5,1,$BJ$2:$BJ$58))

Comment: I'm unclear on what C5 has to do with changing a target within D5:G400 back to a formula.

Comment: Are there possibly procedures in a Worksheet_Change that you do not want initiated on a formula/value change?

Answer (score 1):

Check the current value of Target and revert to the original formula if the cell already contains *Done*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If not Intersect(Target, Range("D5:G400")) is nothing then
        cancel = true
        select case lcase(target.value)
            case "done"
                target.formular1c1 = range("S5").formular1c1
                'option for formula from corresponding row in column S
                'target.formular1c1 = cells(target.row, "S").formular1c1
            case else
                'next line to go with option above
                'cells(target.row, "S").formular1c1 = target.formular1c1
                target = "Done"
        end select
    end if

End Sub
```

You can only ever double-click on a single cell; checking for multiple cells as Target is unnecessary.

An xlR1C1 style formula will not change for any row down a column unless you've made everything an absolute reference. I find it unlikely that you would type out 396 absolute reference formulas so any formula from column S should be fine for any cell in D5:G400.

Comment: You need to go back and edit your question to include the formula stored in column S and clarify what column C has to do with things. Meanwhile, I will [edit] in an option above.

Comment: @Paul - I believe the formula in column S should be `=WORKDAY($C5, 1, $BG$2:$BG$58)`. If you look at the option I provided, passing the formula from column D to S before Done then using that formula coming back should also resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi Jeeped , thanks a lot that done the trick , i  them managed to sort it out for other columns

Answer (score 0):

I'm a tad confused by the wording of your question, but here's my understanding of it:

- user double clicks on a range

  - sub changes the range's value(s) to "Done"
- user double clicks on the range again

  - sub changes the range's value(s) back to what it was before, assuming the sub was called on it previously

My approach would be to simply keep a secondary worksheet and store values there, something along these lines:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick( _ ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rInt As Range, rCell As Range
    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("D5:G400"))

    Dim backup As Excel.Worksheet
    Set backup = Worksheets("backup") ' be sure to create this worksheet beforehand

    If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each rCell In rInt
            If rCell.Text = "Done" Then
                rCell.Value = backup.Range(rCell)

            Else
                backup.Range(rCell).Value = rCell.Value
                rCell.Value = "Done"
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Set rInt = Nothing
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

I haven't actually tested this code, and I'm a bit rough with the Range object (I don't use VBA for excel all that often, and often just use strings), so you'll probably need to edit it a fair bit, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

I should note that you'd need to create the extra worksheet in excel beforehand with my code.